# What method or class in Ruby can i use to add spaces between each date?

Tags: ruby, terminal, calendar

How can I shift each date/number or add white spaces for the numbers can go under the corresponding Day? Is there a class or method from ruby that i can use? By the way I cant use Date from ruby.

```
class Month
  attr_reader :month, :year

  def initialize( month, year)
    @month = month
    @year = year
  end

  def month_names
    names_of_months = {1 => 'January', 2 => 'February', 3 => 'March', 4 => 'April', 5 => 'May', 6 => 'June', 7 => 'July', 8 => 'August', 9 => 'September', 10 => 'October', 11 => 'November', 12 => 'December'}
     return names_of_months[@month]
  end

  def length
    days_of_months  = {1 => 31, 2 => 28, 3 => 31, 4 => 30, 5 => 31, 6 => 30, 7 => 31, 8 => 31, 9 => 30, 10 => 31, 11 => 30, 12 => 31}

     return days_of_months[@month]
  end


  def to_s
    weekdays = "Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa" <<"\n"
    month    = "#{month_names} #{year}"

   output   =[
     month.center(weekdays.size),
     weekdays
     ].join("\n")
     (1..length).each_slice(7) do |week|
     output << week.join
     output << "\n"
   end
     output
  end

 end
```

This is my Results from Terminal:

```
Failure:
TestMonth#test_to_s_on_jan_2017 [test/test_month.rb:39]
Minitest::Assertion: --- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1,9 +1,8 @@
-"    January 2017
+"    January 2017
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
- 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
- 8  9 10 11 12 13 14
-15 16 17 18 19 20 21
-22 23 24 25 26 27 28
-29 30 31
-
+1234567
+891011121314
+15161718192021
+22232425262728
+293031
"


4 tests, 5 assertions, 3 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Wasn't this answered in answers to your earlier questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908021/how-can-i-make-the-days-of-the-month-be-printed-according-to-each-day-ex-su-mo/29908459#29908459) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908876/how-can-i-get-the-dates-to-fall-on-the-perspective-day/29910858#29910858) (i.e, to use `rjust`)?

Comment: not quite. Because when i use rjust it just moves my whole string over. i want to add spaces to each number in the string

Comment: You need to replace your line, `output << week.join` with `output << week.map { |d| d.to_s.rjust(3) }.join[1..-1]`.  `[1..-1]` removes the leading space in the string, which must be done because you need a width of 2 for Sunday and 3 for each of the other days. This is how `rjust` was used in the answers I referenced. Of course, your code only works for months for which the first day of the month falls on a Sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should add the spacing you want to each day of the week:

```
(1..length).each_slice(7) do |week|
  output << week.map { |day| day.to_s.rjust(3) }.join
  output << "\n"
end
```

But looking at your expected output, you want to remove the first space of each line. To do so, try this:

```
(1..length).each_slice(7) do |week|
  output << week.map { |day| day.to_s.rjust(3) }.join[1..-1]
  output << "\n"
end
```

Notice the `[1..-1]` part, this will remove the first character of each `week` string.

#### Side note

On a side note, you don't need the explicit `return` in your methods or the class variables, since you've defined them as `attr_reader`.

Also, to clean things up a bit you could maybe even refactor the `month_names` method to something like the code below (note that I've change the method name to `month_name`). The same could be done to `length` and even `to_s`, but that's probably a matter of personal taste.

```
def month_name
  month_names[month - 1]
end

private

def month_names
  %w(January February March April May June July August September October November December)
end
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks for explaining it so clearly and good to me. And i like the refactor its so much more cleaner. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`String#rjust`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-rjust) and accompanying examples. It will let you add padding to strings.

Comment: the rjust is just shifting all of them to the right.                                            def to_s
    weekdays = "Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa" <<"\n"
    month    = "#{month_names} #{year}"

    output   =[
      month.center(weekdays.size),
      weekdays
      ].join("\n")
      (1..length).each_slice(7) do |week|
      output << week.join.rjust(10) << " "
      output << "\n"
    end
    output
  end